# GPU usage with Cuda and Pytorch

Tags: gpu, pytorch

When I started to use GPU for ML applications, i went to the task manager to see how much GPU it used and found six different graphs, in which just 2 were showing activity. **Compute_0** and **Copy**. The **Compute_0** had an interval between 85-95 % and **Copy** 5-15 %, but it just represented a 8-12% of the full use of the GPU.

I would like to know how it exactly works and find if there's a way to increase that 8-12% because it's also other graph with title **Compute_1** indicating a constant zero usage, implying (by the name) that it can be used too.

This is the implementation code:

```
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    device = torch.device('cuda:0')
```

I'm working with a NVIDIA GeForce 940MX

Comment: check out [this](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/access-gpu-memory-usage-in-pytorch/3192/7) thread please